# brew re-installing an installed dependency

Tags: postgresql, macos, openssl, homebrew, apple-m1

I need to install `postgres@15` on Mac M1. The issue is that openssl dependency is very funky and it can be only installed manually -- I succeeded [using these instructions](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/21306#issuecomment-1611250842).
I can see openssl installed and registered:

```
$ brew list | grep ssl
openssl@1.1
openssl@3
```

Now, when I try installing `postgres@15` after that, it stills tries to download and build `openssl@3`:

```
$ brew install  postgresql@15

==> Fetching dependencies for postgresql@15: openssl@3, krb5, readline and xz
==> Fetching openssl@3
Warning: Building openssl@3 from source as the bottle needs:
- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /opt/homebrew/Cellar (yours is ~/.homebrew/Cellar)
- HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew (yours is ~/.homebrew)
...
==> Downloading https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v15.5/postgresql-15.5.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d755958092e4fdc1292d88b06c3cb16b2d4bbb1fa31d6221be89af1c31a47d42--postgresql-15.5.tar.bz2
==> Installing dependencies for postgresql@15: openssl@3, krb5, readline and xz
==> Installing postgresql@15 dependency: openssl@3
```

I tried `brew install --ignore-dependencies postgresql@15` but this seems to be disabled in current brew version.

In the installation logs, I see warnings like `- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /opt/homebrew/Cellar (yours is ~/.homebrew/Cellar)`, but I am not quite clear on what they mean and how actionable they are.

Any ideas on how to prevent dependency re-installation?

Comment: When it tries to build openssl@3 from source, is it failing? What's the error there?

Comment: Yes, it is failing (see Github URL issue). The only way I figured to solve it is to use the recipe in that issue https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/21306#issuecomment-1611250842